# 100% Usage by /usr/sbin/apache2 -k start

Tags: apache2, mysql, wordpress

Using `htop`, I found `/usr/sbin/apache2 -k start` to be using almost all the server's CPU and MEM resources. This causes MySQL to crash.

Restarting apache will solve this for a few weeks, and the same problem will occur again.

What may be the problem, and how can we solve it?

Answer (score 1):

Your processes may be leaking memory, or you are allowing more threads than you have memory for.  If the memory leak is slow it may take a while for this to manifest.

https://serverfault.com/questions/694538/limiting-memory-and-cpu-usage-per-httpd-worker-with-apache-mod-wsgi/694621?s=15|0.6421#694621 may provide some guidance

Comment: Thanks. Is it feasible to have a script automatically restart the apache2 service every week?

Comment: @Nyxynyx Yes,  the command `apache2ctl graceful` should do the trick.  It can do the trick.  I would monitor your processes to see if memory is leaking and resolve the issue.